# op-amp + ADC slow reaction

Tags: operational-amplifier, adc, oscilloscope

I have the following schematics:

[image]

If I have a scope probe on VIN, everything works very well. VIN is an amplification of the input and the ADC reports it very well: good accuracy and no delay. But if I don't put the scope probe on VIN, the measurement is problematic and if input drops VIN takes a lot of time to follow. In other words, the scope makes work the circuit. Any idea what I should modify?

Comment: 1. Naming an output node as "VIN" is somewhat confusing. 2. A proper schematic that shows amplifiers as amplifiers would make it much easier to see your problem.

Comment: If you don't have a symbol for TLV2782 in Altium just use any other double opamp IC like TL072 and change the name and footprint.

Comment: Input is an ultrasonic sensor. D5 and D6 was the idea to do a rectifier to have a clean signal to measure.

Comment: In that case get rid of D5, it's doing nothing for you.

Comment: I have removed D5 but still the same: works on the scope, but without it, the ADC report shows a very slow fall. I have also tried to replace D5 by a 2M resistor, but still the same. Any advice?

Comment: @GregoireGentil, Removing D5 changes nothing. It was doing nothing in your circuit. D6 is what's causing your problem, as explained in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The probe adds a path to the ground and it pulls VIN. Add a one-mega-ohm resistor between VIN and ground.

Answer (score 1):

Diode D6 means that the op-amp can only drive the ADC input high. On its own, the amplifier circuit can't pull VIN low.

When you connect the scope probe, you effectively add a resistor to ground, probably in the neighborhood of 1 - 10 Megohms. This pulls VIN low whenever the op-amp isn't driving it high.

Comment: Additionally D5 will never conduct as opamp's output voltage will always be equal or above GND.

Comment: @SzymonBęczkowski, D5 could be there as a protection against turn-on transients or something. But without more context its hard to know exactly what the designer had in mind.

Comment: Input is an ultrasonic sensor. D5 and D6 was the idea to do a rectifier to have a clean signal to measure.

Comment: Your opamp will not output negative voltage so you don't need these two diodes. Diodes will not clean your signal. If you are having problems with noise in your measurement signal just slow down your amplifier.